# Flag changing columns from 0 to value row by row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this example I have a dataset that has two columns `prime` and `prime2` that I want to check for changes in row by row style:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_police':['p123','p123','p123','b123','b123'],
                   'date':['24/01/2017','24/11/2017','25/02/2018','24/02/2018','24/03/2018'],
                   'prime':[0,0,10,20,30],
                   'prime2':[0,30,10,20,0],
})
###
  id_police        date  prime  prime2
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0      30
2      p123  25/02/2018     10      10
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0
```

This is the expected result *(if two columns change, the flag is anything but 0, and add them in changedwhere, also, there is 10 columns like prime & prime2)*:

```
  id_police        date  prime  prime2  changed  changedwhere(optional)
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0<-      0           nan
1      p123  24/11/2017      0<-    30<-      1        prime2
2      p123  25/02/2018     10<-    10        1         prime
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20        0           nan
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0        0           nan
```

What I tried but it looks in all columns:

```
df.diff()
```

Thanks in advance for your help, if any questions feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: What if two colums change?

Comment: If two change, then it's flagged also as 1 or any value except 0. And include them both as changedwhwere(optional)

Comment: Also, in the production I have like 10 columns as prime & prime2... please help! thank u!

Comment: You should include that in your question, since that makes it quite more complex

Comment: I have added that.

Comment: Your output does not make sense, in every row one of the two columns changed compared to the row before, except the first row obviously.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Why row 3, 4 changed is 0?

Comment: Because change as in the title is from 0 to a value...

Comment: Please provide any hints or guidance as I will be able to adapt your solution to what is actually needed... Thank you so much!

Comment: I added arrows in the expected result for clarity.

Comment: I can give you an answer which makes the `changed` column, but not the names of the column yet.

Comment: Thanks man! Its optional.

Comment: how would you want to compare the third column then? with lag of 2 for `prime3` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Series.eq` over `axis=1` and combine it with `.shift` to check the previous row like following:

```
df['changed'] = (df[['prime', 'prime2']].shift().eq(0).any(axis=1) & df[['prime', 'prime2']].ne(0).any(axis=1)).astype(int)

print(df)
  id_police        date  prime  prime2  changed
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0        0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0      30        1
2      p123  25/02/2018     10      10        1
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20        0
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0        0
```

**Note**, if you have 10 columns, this will be more difficult, but for your example, this suffices

Comment: Pandas :) @SabiriS.

Comment: There is only one problem, how can I add this to the groupby `id_police` because this rule is applied for each id_police...

Comment: You can ask that in a new question. This question for now is answered. You can always copy the link here in the comments and tag me, I can have a look at it.

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665413/flag-changing-column-in-a-groupby-dataframe-using-pandas) me, thanks!