# Flag changing column in a groupby DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the dataset:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_police':['p123','p123','p123','b123','b123'],
                   'date':['24/01/2017','24/11/2017','25/02/2018','24/02/2018','24/03/2018'],
                   'prime':[0,0,10,20,30],
                   'prime2':[0,30,10,20,0],
})
###
  id_police        date  prime  prime2
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0      30
2      p123  25/02/2018     10      10
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0
```

This is the result I got when I used the working solution from @Erfan:

```
  id_police        date  prime  prime2  changed
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0<-      0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0<-    30<-      1
2      p123  25/02/2018     10<-    10        1
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20        0
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0        0
```

The command:

```
df['changed'] = (df[['prime', 'prime2']].shift().eq(0).any(axis=1) & df[['prime', 'prime2']].ne(0).any(axis=1)).astype(int)
```

Now I want to apply this for each `id_police` like add a groupby or something... Thanks for help!

Comment: There is p123 and b123....

Comment: Your expected output is still the same?

Comment: Yes but within each id_police...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based On your command:

```
cols = ['prime', 'prime2']

df['changed'] = (df.groupby('id_police', sort=False, as_index=False)
                   .apply(lambda x: (x[cols].ne(0) & x[cols].shift(1).eq(0))
                   .any(axis=1).astype(int))
                   .reset_index(drop=True))
df

  id_police        date  prime  prime2  changed
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0        0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0      30        1
2      p123  25/02/2018     10      10        1
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20        0
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0        0
```

Use `groupby` with `apply` to apply function on each group. and set `sort=False` to make it order the same with your main df.

Comment: @SabiriS. Without loop would speed up :)

Comment: Please, I need to add another condition (or) like this:
`.apply(lambda x: (x[cols].ne(0) & (x[cols].shift(1).eq(0)) or (x[cols].shift(2).eq(0)))` but it doesn't work... I appreciate your help.

Comment: @SabiriS. Replace `or` with `|`

Comment: @SabiriS. Pandas [Info Page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info) is full of useful content, you can try to read it.

Answer (score 2):

We can acces the groupid and groups in our `groupby object` and then make the `changed` columns in each iteration:

```
groups = []
for _, grp in df.groupby('id_police'):
    grp['changes'] = (grp[['prime', 'prime2']].shift().eq(0).any(axis=1) & grp[['prime', 'prime2']].ne(0).any(axis=1)).astype(int)
    groups.append(grp)

df_final = pd.concat(groups).sort_index()
```

---

Which yields

```
print(df_final)
  id_police        date  prime  prime2  changes
0      p123  24/01/2017      0       0        0
1      p123  24/11/2017      0      30        1
2      p123  25/02/2018     10      10        1
3      b123  24/02/2018     20      20        0
4      b123  24/03/2018     30       0        0
```

---

If you want to turn off the `SetCopyWarning`, use the following:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```